# Создание двумерного словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить скрипт:

```
import shelve

db = shelve.open('data')
keys = ['id', 'type', 'number'];

def outputDB(db):
    for record in db:
        print(record, ': ', db[record])
        for item in db[record]:    
            print(item, '--', db[record][item])
        print('-----')

while 1:
    action = int(input('1 - print, 2 - write'))

    if(action == 1):
        outputDB(db)
        break
    else:
        index = input('введите индекс')
        db[index] = dict()
        for key in keys:
            print('enter value for ', key)
            value = str(input('enter value: '))
            db[index][key] = value
        outputDB(db)
db.close()    
print('stop')
```

По моей задумке, здесь должно происходить следующее: пользователь выбирает режим ввода (то есть вводит число 2). Далее ему предлагается заполнить двумерный словарь (db). Он вводит индекс первого уровня (db[index]) и 3 значения для второго уровня словаря (набор ключей определён в начале скрипта). Таким образом, должен получаться словарь с двумя уровнями вложенности. Словарь сохраняется обращением к стандартному модулю shelve.
После перезапуска скрипта пользователь может вывести в консоль содержание словаря db, введя 1,
Но вместо словаря с двумя уровнями вложенности, почему-то в консоль выводится примерно следующее:

```
q :  {}
-----
a :  {}
-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте промежуточную переменную, значение которой помещайте в db:

```
import shelve

db = shelve.open('data')
keys = ['id', 'type', 'number'];

def outputDB(db):
    for record in db:
        print(record, ': ', db[record])
        for item in db[record]:    
            print(item, '--', db[record][item])
        print('-----')

while 1:
    action = int(input('1 - print, 2 - write'))

    if(action == 1):
        outputDB(db)
        break
    else:
        index = input('введите индекс')
        temp = dict()
        for key in keys:
            print('enter value for ', key)
            value = str(input('enter value: '))
            temp[key] = value
        db[index] = temp
        outputDB(db)
db.close()    
print('stop')
```